# how to give Live Streaming through single channel

Tags: android, live-streaming, email, accountmanager, youtube-channels

I am doing an android app in YouTube Live streaming. so, I created one channel in YouTube. so all the users have to use this single channel through my app for Live streaming. So , one channel for all the users in the sense, each user have to aware about the credentials of that YouTube channel (email account). I think this is not a good implementation. My idea was, if we implement channel's credentials inside our code, no need to inform the users about the credentials.

How can I achieve this (using that channel email account in my code) without showing the all the emails which are in my device to access the YouTube?

I am confused how to implement this.

Comment: `we implement channel's credentials inside our code` - `how to implement this` - you don't, you shouldn't, unless it is encrypted with an external key.

Comment: Hello @basha. May I know if you have used any code in Github as basis for this app that you made?

Comment: Hello there! Is there any reference code that you based this project from?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by adding Google Credential object with access token and refresh token and secret key . It is working fine now

```
 googleCredential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().
                                setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setTransport(transport).
                                setClientSecrets("clientid", "secretkey")
                                .build();
                        googleCredential.setAccessToken("*********");
                        googleCredential.setRefreshToken("*****");
```